# How to add column into dataframe in pandas bases on other dataframe using 2 condition columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dears, I need help to know with methodology can I apply to solve the math issue below using Python and Pandas.

I have the following pandas data frame:

```
df1 = 
PRODUCT | YEAR | QTD |
Table | 2020 | 110 |
Pencil| 2021 | 220 | 
Car | 2019 | 330 |
```

and the second one:

```
df2 = 
PRODUCT | YEAR | PRICE |
Table | 2019 | 0.5 |
Table | 2020 | 0.7 |
Pencil| 2019 | 190 |
Pencil| 2020 | 210 | 
Pencil| 2021 | 220 |  
Car | 2019 | 310 |
Car | 2020 | 320 |
Car | 2021 | 330 |
```

How to merge two dataframe to create a unique one like below:

```
df_Result = 
PRODUCT | YEAR | QTD | PRICE
Table | 2020 | 110 | 0.7
Pencil| 2021 | 220 | 220
Car | 2019 | 330 | 310
```

How to create the conditions to check the PRODUCT and YEAR to add a column PRICE correspondent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the `merge()` function here. Merge is similar to a join in SQL, if you are familiar with that.

If not, the idea is that you specify which columns it should match on and 'how' you want the join to work

So here, you would have

```py
df_result = pd.merge(left=df1,right=df2,how='left',on=['PRODUCT','YEAR'])
```

Comment: Dear @scotscotmcc your answer help me a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

use `left` [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html):

```
merged_df = df1.merge(df2, on = ['PRODUCT', 'YEAR'], how = 'left')
```

#### OUTPUT

```
  PRODUCT    YEAR    QTD    PRICE 
0   Table     2020    110      0.7
1   Pencil    2021    220    220.0
2     Car     2019    330    310.0
```